# getting capybara to work with vue.js in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, capybara, vue.js

I recently added a feature in vuejs and am having trouble testing it.

I created a spec file for simply visiting the page but anything on my html that has logic such as a `v-show` does not get rendered in the test. I added an onload to see if it might render

```
window.onload = function () {
  new Vue({
    el: 'body',
    ....
  });
}
```

but upon running the spec I still get multiple vue warnings like this:

```
[Vue warn]: Error when evaluating expression "settingIds.includes(setting.id)": TypeError: 'undefined' is not a
function (evaluating 'scope.settingsIds.includes(scope.setting.id)')`
```

Note: I am using localstorage which some of my view logic depends on and I'm not sure if capybara supports it

Comment: What driver are you using?

Comment: @TomWalpole Poltergeist

Comment: assuming settingsIds is an Array - `includes` is an ES7 method which is not supported by PhantomJS or IE (the latest 2.1.1 which you should be running supports is ES5) - you'd need to rewrite your code not using ES6/7 methods or polyfill using the poltergeist extensions option

Comment: @TomWalpole thanks, that fixed it

Comment: Added it as an answer so you can mark the question fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming settingsIds is an Array - includes is an ES7 method which is not supported by PhantomJS or IE (the latest PhantomJS 2.1.1, which you should be running, supports is ES5) - you'd need to rewrite your code not using ES6/7 methods, transcode it to ES5, or polyfill using the poltergeist extensions option